# Как открыть модальное окно из menuItem

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

**GeneralWindow.fxml**

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="407.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="net.komus.fxControllers.MainController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="navigationBar" prefHeight="412.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
            <MenuBar fx:id="myMenuBar" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
              <menus>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Файл">
                  <items>
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemConfigure" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#openModalWindowConfigure" text="Настройки" />
                        <MenuItem fx:id="menuItemExit" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeApplication" text="Выход" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
                <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Помощь">
                  <items>
                    <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="О программе" />
                  </items>
                </Menu>
              </menus>
            </MenuBar>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="338.0" prefWidth="554.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="29.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="20.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="29.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Имя" />
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Фамилия" />
                        <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="VOIP" />
                    </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="20.0" top="20.0" />
               </padding>
            </AnchorPane>
            <AnchorPane prefHeight="30.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="7.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0">
               <children>
                  <Button layoutX="20.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Загрузить" />
                  <Button disable="true" layoutX="119.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Сохранить" />
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**MainController**

```
    public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private Parent root;

    @FXML 
    MenuBar myMenuBar; // Меню аккордион

    @FXML
    MenuItem menuItemExit;

    @FXML
    MenuItem menuItemConfigure;

    /**
     * Закрыть окно.
     * 
     * @param actionEvent
     */
    @FXML
    public void closeApplication( ActionEvent actionEvent ) {
        Stage stage = (Stage) myMenuBar.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();

    }

    /**
     * Открыть модальное окно настроек программы
     * 
     * @param actionEvent
     */
    @FXML
    public void openModalWindowConfigure( ActionEvent actionEvent ) {       
        try {
            // Stage stage = (Stage) myMenuBar.getScene().getWindow();
            Stage stage = (Stage) root.getScene().getWindow();

            // Загрузка FXML
            Parent fxml = FXMLLoader.load( getClass().getResource( "../fxml/EditWindow.fxml" ) );

            stage.setTitle( "Настройки" );
            stage.setResizable( false );

            // Создание окна
            stage.setScene( new Scene( fxml ) );
            stage.setMinWidth( 600 );
            stage.setMinHeight( 300 );
            stage.initModality( Modality.WINDOW_MODAL );
            stage.initOwner( ( (Node) actionEvent.getSource() ).getScene().getWindow() );
            //stage.initOwner( stage );

            // Показать модальное окно
            stage.show();

        } catch ( IOException ioe ) {
            // Если файл не найден
            System.out.println( ioe.getMessage() );
        }
    }
}
```

при нажатии на `menuItem` получаю ошибку:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$6(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$5(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot set modality once stage has been set visible
    at javafx.stage.Stage.initModality(Stage.java:525)
    at net.komus.fxControllers.MainController.openModalWindowConfigure(MainController.java:63)
    ... 53 more
```

Так как `menuItem` не является подклассом `Node` я не понимаю как мне получить `Node` от `menuItem`.

Comment: Как делать модалки правильно ->
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/10488434/4444092

Comment: Там вообще нет ничего про menuItem. Вы хотите сказать что вызов модального окна из menuItem это не есть хорошо?

Comment: Я хочу сказать что само модальное окно Вы открываете не правильно, отсюда и ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено. Получать Node не обязательно, можно получить window от menuItem:

```
MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)actionEvent.getTarget();
ContextMenu cMenu = menuItem.getParentPopup();
Scene scene = cMenu.getScene();
Window window = scene.getWindow();
```

В итоге код метода **openModalWindowConfigure** выглядит вот так:

```
    /**
     * Открыть модальное окно настроек программы
     * 
     * @param actionEvent
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    @FXML
    public void openModalWindowConfigure( ActionEvent actionEvent ) throws IOException {                    
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/EditWindow.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Редактирование записи");
        stage.setMinHeight(150);
        stage.setMinWidth(300);
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        // Получить window menuItem
        MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)actionEvent.getTarget();
        ContextMenu cMenu = menuItem.getParentPopup();
        Scene scene = cMenu.getScene();
        Window window = scene.getWindow();

        stage.initOwner( window );
        stage.show();

    }
```

П.С. главное окно не доступно для изменений, за это отвечает как я понял параметр stage.initModality(Modality.**APPLICATION_MODAL**);

Конечно я не уверен является ли мое решение правильным с точки зрения Java, но программа выполняется так как и задумывалось.